# Inserting a row into a pandas dataframe based on row value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, insert

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[2,1,2],'C':['a','b','a']})
  B C
0 2 'a'
1 1 'b'
2 2 'a'
```

I want to insert a row above any occurrence of 'b', that is a duplicate of that row but with 'b' changed to 'c', so I end up with this:

```
  B C
0 2 'a'
1 1 'b'
1 1 'c'
2 2 'a'
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: you said above but in output its below, your first df produces `a` instead of `c` in third row.

Comment: What if there are two consecutive rows with `b`?

Comment: @shivsn sorry, typo

Comment: @Divakar, that's unlikely to happen, but if it did, then I would just insert a 'c' row above each one of the 'b' rows

Comment: Are you happy with a loop?

Comment: @IanS, happy with anything honestly. MadScone seems to have nailed it though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
duplicates = df[df['C'] == 'b'].copy()
duplicates['C'] = 'c'
df.append(duplicates).sort_index()
```

Comment: Beautiful, didn't realize there was a copy function!

Answer (score 1):

Working at NumPy level, here's a vectorized approach -

```
arr = df.values
idx = np.flatnonzero(df.C=='b')
newvals = arr[idx]
newvals[:,df.columns.get_loc("C")] = 'c'
out = np.insert(arr,idx+1,newvals,axis=0)
df_index = np.insert(np.arange(arr.shape[0]),idx+1,idx,axis=0)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out,index=df_index)
```

Sample run -

```
In [149]: df
Out[149]: 
   B  C
0  2  a
1  1  b
2  2  d
3  4  d
4  3  b
5  8  a
6  4  a
7  2  b

In [150]: df_out
Out[150]: 
   0  1
0  2  a
1  1  b
1  1  c
2  2  d
3  4  d
4  3  b
4  3  c
5  8  a
6  4  a
7  2  b
7  2  c
```